# Problems with passing data to Javascript from a Rails view via <%= content_tag %>

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm rather new to Rails and to programming in general, and I'm having issues passing data from a `<%= content_tag %>` in a Rails view to a Javascript function (in this case, specifically making use of `fullcalendar`). Inspecting the rendered page's HTML source shows the data properly ending up in the resulting `div`, but the data from it doesn't seem to make it into the Javascript function that's supposed to be referencing it.

The problem is probably something very basic since I have no previous experience with Javascript, but copious googling has not shown me any solutions.

The view contains the following `content_tag`:

```
<%= content_tag :div, "", class: "calendar_data", data: {start_date: '2021-10-12', end_date: '2021-10-19'} do %>
<% end %>
```

(Once this is working I'll replace those dates with variables.)

The relevant section of my `application.js` includes the following code:

```
function loadCalendar() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [timeGridPlugin],
    initialView: 'timeGrid',
    visibleRange: {
      start: $('.calendar_data').data('start_date'),
      end: $('.calendar_data').data('end_date')
    }
  });

  calendar.render();
};
```

Replacing the `$('.calendar_data').data('start_date')` and `end_date` bits with plain dates as strings (e.g. `'2021-10-12'`) produces the expected behaviour, which is why it seems like what's going on is that those `$. ...` bits are failing to return the data they're supposed to be looking for. As far as I understand it, that data *should* be available, given that the rendered page's HTML contains a `div` with the expected content:

```
<div class="calendar_data" data-start-date="2021-10-12" data-end-date="2021-10-19">
</div>
```

(For completeness's sake, yes, I have installed jquery and `application.js` includes `import $ from 'jquery'`.)

What am I doing wrong here? What basic principle of this process have I failed to properly google for?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked around this by making `calendar_data` an id rather than a class in the `content_tag`, and taking advantage of Javascript's `getElementById` and `dataset` functionality:

The resulting `application.js` code is this:

```
function loadCalendar() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendarData = document.getElementById('calendar_data');
  var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [timeGridPlugin],
    initialView: 'timeGrid',
    visibleRange: {
      start: calendarData.dataset.startDate,
      end: calendarData.dataset.endDate
    }
  });

  calendar.render();
};
```